# Android Layout Weight Does Not Work

Tags: android, android-layout

Im building this app, just want to distribute these buttons equally on the screen, this is the code i`m using:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/tera_mt_serv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="teraServerBt"
    android:background="@color/gblue"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="@string/tera_server_st_mt_ab"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tera_ff_serv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gblue"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="@string/tera_server_st_ff_ab"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tera_ch_serv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gblue"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:onClick="teraServerBt"
    android:text="@string/tera_server_st_ch_ab"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tera_av_serv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gblue"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="@string/tera_server_st_av_ab"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tera_tr_serv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gblue"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="@string/tera_server_st_tr_ab"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
```

But I Still get this result, even when i test it on my phone:

[APP RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPVzT.jpg)

Im new on this so it must be something simple that I can`t see. Anyway, Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Seems your view is not occupying full width. Use match_parent width for root view

Answer (score 2):

Set your parent LinearLayout's width to match_parent, then your buttons should share the space of the full width equally.

Comment: It Worked Thanks Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

On your LinearLayout set `android:weightSum="1"` and set `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

After that, on each button set `android:layout_weight="0.20"`

Remember : **0.20 (each layout_weight) x 5 (buttons) = 1 weightSum**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tera_mt_serv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:onClick="teraServerBt" 
        android:textColor="#fff" 
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tera_ff_serv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#fff" 
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tera_ch_serv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:onClick="teraServerBt" 
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tera_av_serv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#fff" 
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tera_tr_serv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#fff" 
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        tools:ignore="ButtonStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It Worked Thanks Very Much!

Comment: @WildmarGomes Is good to know. "Thumbs up" for my answer, right?:)